# Managing multiple connections to a DB in Java

Tags: java, database, heroku, database-connection

I have a JAX-RS server that is hosted by heroku. Currently, we create one Connection to the DB (at startup) and all SQL statements acquire a lock, use the connection and release the lock. As we prepare to scale the application, this probably won't work. I was planning to make a queue of connections to the same DB so we can run multiple SQL statements in parallel.

Is there an easy way to do this? I was hoping there would be something similar to a java's ThreadPool, but for DB Connections.

I feel like this problem of scaling up the connections to a DB from a webserver has been done many times and would like to do it the right way. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connection pool lib, check out [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/).